# Configurando eslint com adonisjs

Tags: adonisjs, eslint

Estou tentando configurar o eslint em um projeto que utiliza AdonisJS porém ele me pergunta qual tipo de módulos o projeto usa, Javascript Modules, CommonJS ou nenhum desses.

- Alguém poderia me informar qual tipo de módulo o AdonisJS usa?

Answer (score 1):

Quando eu estudei Adonis, se recomendava escolher "Nenhum desses".

Aqui tem um passo a passo de como configurar o ESLint para AdonisJS

https://danielobara.wordpress.com/2019/06/07/configurando-uma-api-do-zero-em-adonisjs/